# What is the maximally efficient way to cover all time with workers that have different work-rest ratios and costs.

Tags: logic, puzzle

You're a farmer. The crop on this farm must be harvested 24 hours per day, indefinitely. You have four levels of farmhands from which you can hire that can do the harvesting, each level with a different length of time they can work. Every farmhand has a mandatory rest period of 30 hours.

```
Farmhands
Level   -   Can Work  -   Cost
Level 1 -   8 hours   -   1 unit
Level 2 -   10 hours  -   1.5 units
Level 3 -   12 hours  -   2 units
Level 4 -   20 hours  -   8 units
```

Again - every farmhand (regardless of level) has a 30 hour rest period. Your goal is to hire the minimum number of farmhands, at the lowest cumulative rate, ensuring 24/7/365 coverage. You can hire multiple of any level and not all levels need be used (ex: 2x level 1 + 1x level 4 + 3x level 2). It does not matter in which order the farmhands work, and the order can change over time if necessary.

This is for a strategy game I am working on. I have attempted to solve by charting the work and rest periods, but I still have days that farmhands are idle for hours at a time and feel like there must be a formula or equation that can be used to solve this. The best I could come up with is 5x Level 1s for a total cost of 5 units, but the 1st farmhand sits idle after his rest period for 2 hours waiting for the 5th farmhand to complete his work rotation. I am trying to eliminate that idle time.

Comment: FIRST QUESTION REVIEW: Welcome in Math SE. The question is well-formulated but the part about your personal thoughts is missing. As it is now, your question seems to be copied from a math book. Moreover, you should put your formulas in $Mathjax$. See the Quick Beginner Guide for Asking Questions (link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/1107523) for more informations. It will take you only 2 minutes to read it and will help you getting answers faster. Have a nice day !

Comment: Thanks @AlbertSchrödinberg! I will review the guide.

Comment: Updated the question. Is this more in-line with expectations, @AlbertSchrödinberg?

Comment: Yes, it is much better now.